# rails3 routing syntax based on variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

I have

> resources :staticpages

The Model has attributes, whose presence is validated:  category_id and path

And I am trying to serve up the show pages as /category.name/path
The following syntax is not being recognised

```
  match 'staticpage/:id', :to => redirect("/%{category.name/%{path}")
```

Returns unknown action

COMMENT ADDED HERE RE First answer (comments' not accepting at present...)
Maybe I'm confusing myself, by the fact that models and controllers bear the same name... Anyhow, should it not be match 'staticpages/:id'?

But I fail to see how in the controller I can state more than @staticpage.category.name and @staticpage.path to generate the new route?

Also, as I have to avoid stomping on other models/controllers, I need to keep some form of sanity (where page is NOT a controller and path validates as unique): 'page/category.name/path'

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `redirect()` in `routes.rb`

Routes match to a `Controller#action`, not a `Model`.

You'll need to create a controller with appropriate actions, and match them to a route.

Something like this:

```
match 'staticpage/:id', to: staticpages#show
```

This will redirect anything matching `/staticpages/` to the `show` action of the `staticpages` controller.

Then within the `show` action (which will be a method in your `staticpages` controller), you can grab the `:id` from the `params` hash and use it to render/redirect/etc.

Source: [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html)